# "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: fillbuf

Tags: java, swing

i got a problem...

i have a component made it in swing, i call one webservice to get a Clob file, all works perfectly, but in special a few times o got the error "java.lang.InternalError: fillbuf" does somebody knows what means?

Just happens a few times..

Thanks in advance.

Im using JDK 5

Comment: You'll get much better help if you post some code, preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also the full stack trace of your exception might help.

Comment: @ulmangt: It might be hard to create an SSCCE for this problem since it is infrequent (as most Swing thread issues tend to be).

Comment: Please elaborate on what [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) you use to get a [CLOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_large_object).

Answer (score 1):

Intermittent errors such as the above are almost always due to concurrency issues. Are you taking care to make all Swing calls on the EDT?

In other words, any code in a background thread that needs to make Swing calls should queue the call on the event queue by wrapping the call in a Runnable like so:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      // your Swing calls go here
   }
});
```

Comment: If you do not want to check all your code for Swing threading violations, consider using the [`CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager`](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html). I am a big fan of this class, and use it frequently

Comment: Hello everybody, im cheking and the swing button go to one webservice, this webservice got CDATA field where i put an XML, this actions sometimes give me the error, but so many others not. The size of the file into the CDATA that dont get error is 3.55 Kb, and the file with error got 3.58 Kb, its just a little difference, i try to quit the XML and just pass a common string... and work perfectly. Any another idea? Thanks